# How to create a new record using the values from a variable already under the same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I remove records all the time to test, and need to re-create the same record to test again.

So doing this:

```
User.create(name: "Peter", col1: "etc", col2: "etc", ...)
u = User.last
User.last.delete
```

**How to accomplish something like this?**:

```
User.create(u)
```

`u` is already an instance of `User` class`:

```
u.class => User(id: integer, name: string, ...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to accomplish something like this?:
>
> `User.create(u)`

`create` accepts the hash, so you can pass the hash key-value pairs of all `u` attributes (except for `id`):

```
User.create(u.attributes.except('id'))
```

Note, that it will fail if you have *any* uniqueness validation.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be as simple as:

```
User.create!(u.attributes)
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use this : 
   `User.create!(u.attributes)`

it will give you error ' ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique '

**You can use this. It will create new record with new id**

`User.create(u.attributes.except('id'))`